# Saving collection using PhoneApplicationService.Current.State

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to save a collection where a store a diagnostic log temporarily when navigating away from my app - I've looked at other sample code and it seems pretty basic as I've done below:

Saving:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["DiagnosticLog"] = DiagnosticLog;
```

Loading:

```
if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("DiagnosticLog"))
  DiagnosticLog = (ObservableCollection<DiagnosticLogEntry>)
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["DiagnosticLog"];
```

However I get this error:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when this happens, it means you do not have a default public constructor on your Diagnostic class (or one of it's contained classes).

Comment: Thanks, that was it ... just made a blank constructor and it worked